# Get Array data into table - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

An asp:DataList has generated the below html. A Q&A form, where each set has the Qno, Question and options.

```
 //Repeating Set
<table id="tblQuestions" class="tblQuestions">
 <tr><td><span class="lbQno">1</span><span>First question</span></td></tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <table class="clOptions">
     <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" value="1/><label>sometext</label</td>
      <td><input type="radio" value="2/><label>sometext</label</td>
      <td><input type="radio" value="3/><label>sometext</label</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

On a button click, I would like to check that all questions are answered.

**JS:**

```
//Get the questionslist
//Loop thro' them, assigning each list to a table.
// and then get the Qno and optionslist in that table

var QuestionsList = document.getElementsByClassName("tblQuestions");
function AllQuestionsAnswered() {

   for(var i = 0;i<QuestionsList.length;i++)
   {
      var tbl = QuestionsList[i];                    
      var OptionsList = $('tbl.clOptions input:radio');

      $('tbl tr').each(function () {
             var QuestionNo = $(this).find('.lbQno').text();
             if(QuestionId > 0){                 
              //perform check on each radiobutton of question
             }                        
      });
   }
}
```

I am failing here on how to get the controls. All the 3 definitions inside the for loop arent working. How should I proceed further.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` should be `getElementById`. You are also missing some `"` and `>` in your html

Comment: ID of an element must be unique.. so you can't have the same table structure repeated for each question

Comment: So it should be `class="tblQuestions"` in HTML

Comment: Sorry about that. The table has also the class with the same name. Now updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that you can correct all problems with HTML:

- missing `"` in `input`'s value.
- missing `name` for `input`s.
- missing `>` for `</label>`.

Then you can use this code for check all necessary questions.

- Filter all questions that should be checked (based on `.lbQno` text).
- For each filtered questions:

  - Get length of selected radio buttons for current question.
  - If there is no selected radio buttons (`length` equals to `0`), then show an error and stop checking.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function filterElement()
    {
        return parseInt($(this).find(".lbQno").text()) > 0;
    }

    $('#check').click(function()
    {
        $(".tblQuestions").filter(filterElement).each(function()
        {
            var checkedCount = $(this).find('.clOptions input:radio:checked').length;
            if (!checkedCount)
            {
                alert($(this).find(".lbQno").next().text() + " is not answered");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o22dqx0n/).

Related HTML:

```
<table id="tblQuestions1" class="tblQuestions">
 <tr><td><span class="lbQno">1</span><span>First question</span></td></tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <table class="clOptions">
     <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"/><label>sometext</label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="2"/><label>sometext</label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="3"/><label>sometext</label></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table id="tblQuestions2" class="tblQuestions">
 <tr><td><span class="lbQno">1</span><span>Second question</span></td></tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <table class="clOptions">
     <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1"/><label>sometext</label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2"/><label>sometext</label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="3"/><label>sometext</label></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table id="tblQuestions3" class="tblQuestions">
 <tr><td><span class="lbQno">0</span><span>Unnecessary question</span></td></tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <table class="clOptions">
     <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q0" value="1"/><label>sometext</label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q0" value="2"/><label>sometext</label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q0" value="3"/><label>sometext</label></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<input id="check" type="button" value="check"/>
```